# Assigning to a double-indexed numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I know that when assigning to a double indexed-array gives bad results because you're assigning to a view rather then to an array directly, but I cannot figure out how to properly assign to double-indexed array:

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
bar = np.array([False, True, True, True, False])
foo[bar][1:2] = np.array([30, 40])
foo #array([1, 2, 30, 40, 5])
```

Is there a way to assign a value(array) to doubly-indexed array?

Comment: If I follow the logic, you want to index using both a boolean array and a slice of the True values in this array? (like "the last two True")? Btw, shouldn't your slice be `[1:]` or `[1:3]` (else you only have **one** element)?

Comment: Actually, the problem is thar `foo[bar]` is a copy. It would be ok if it was a `view`.

Comment: Yeah, I might have missled the index by one. What I meant is that the first boolean index selects the middle three elements, and then I want to replace the second and third one by an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to index using both a boolean array and a slice of the True values in this array, you would need to compute another boolean array that summarizes those conditions.

Here is a possible approach based on the indices of the boolean array:

```
idx = np.arange(len(bar))
foo[idx[bar][1:3]] = np.array([30, 40])
```

output: `array([ 1,  2, 30, 40,  5])`

Comment: yep, I had trouble rewriting the double index to single index. thanks